# Facing Issue While creating a new react project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, linux, mern

I entered this command in terminal npm install create-react-app my-app
and getting this issue.Not able to create project

npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote git://github.scm.corp.ebay.com/cubejs/cluster2.git
npm ERR! fatal: unable to look up github.scm.corp.ebay.com (port 9418) (Name or service not known)

I tried these options
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

npm install aframe

Comment: create-react-app is deprecated, try using vite `npm create vite@latest`

Answer (score 0):

The command to create new react project is `npx create-react-app my-app`. Assuming you already have nodejs installed.
I hope it helps.

[Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please your nodejs installed first.
This is the command to check your node version
node -v
You can try another way to create a new react project

**npx**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

**npm**

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

available in npm 6+

**yarn**

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

available in Yarn 0.25+

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching to Vite instead. (This is how I create my projects)

```
npm create vite@latest
```

Then select your required framework and language (TS/JS)

```
create-vite@5.1.0
Ok to proceed? (y) y
✔ Project name: … sample
✔ Select a framework: › React
? Select a variant: › - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
❯   TypeScript
    TypeScript + SWC
    JavaScript
    JavaScript + SWC
```

I think `create-react-app` is either deprecated or about to be deprecated and might contain dependences that are not updated. Anyhow it should be a good time to switch to a different tooling for new react projects.

For a detailed guide visit the Vite's [get started](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) page.